# How to create a indicator on top of each entity using A-Frame for VR?

Tags: javascript, web, aframe, virtual-reality

I am using A-Frame for VR and I am looking for a way to pin a second entity on the top of all other A-Frame entities like the black diamond in the image below:

[image]

I have 2 main challenges:

- place automatically the diamond: I am able to place it relatively to its parent as a child but I need to manage myself the size of the parent to be sure the child is not inside the parent
- rotated the diamong in order to get it perpendicular to the user view at every moment.

To be honest, I would like to recreate a indicator visible on top of each entity on the screen like in watch dog 2 for example (in the example the diamond is white on the top of the car).

[image]

I don't see any easy to do it with A-Frame and I would like to know if I need to code it by myself or if there is something that could help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to focus on the so called main challenges:

2) Rotating the indicator. You can use Ngo Kevin's [look-at](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/look-at/) component, which rotates an entity to face any given entity.

Example:

```
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" look-at="#player" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-camera id="player" position="0 1.6 0"></a-camera>
```

Live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mzdubuuf/1/).

---

1) Placing above the entity. I'd use [bounding boxes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3) to determine the height. Then create your diamond, place the it about `0.2` above the objects height. and set any other attributes (material, src, text)

Example:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
 init: function() {
    var object = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
    var position = {x:0, y: bbox.max.y + 0.2, z:0}
    var diamond = document.createElement("a-box")
    diamond.setAttribute("color", "green")
    diamond.setAttribute("width", "0.1")
    diamond.setAttribute("height", "0.1")
    diamond.setAttribute("depth", "0.1")
    diamond.setAttribute("position", position)
    diamond.setAttribute("look-at", "#player")
    this.el.appendChild(diamond)
  }
})
```

```
<a-box foo></a-box>
```

live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mzdubuuf/3/)